# .net core - Model virtual property not loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In my .net core 2 project, I have user and file model and they have relationship. In model and in database;

user model :

```
[DefaultValue(null)]
public int? AvatarId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AvatarId")]
public virtual File Avatar { get; set; }
```

file model :

```
[InverseProperty("Avatar")]
public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

I get my user with this query

```
var user = this._db.User.Include(u => u.Avatar).FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
```

in context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne<File>(u => u.Avatar)
            .WithMany(f => f.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.AvatarId);
```

If user have avatar or dont have a avatar, Avatar property return null.

Comment: Check the database, is there any value for `AvatarId` in `User`? And make sure `AvatarId` is not null.

Comment: Yes it is, i check every thing

Comment: Is there any reproduceable project?

Comment: no, i define relationship in database, models, and in context and record have value, but not working

Comment: thanks to "TanvirArjel" problem solved by install EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies and add UseLazyLoadingProxies()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lazy loading for virtual navigation property does not support in Entity Framework Core 2.0.

It has been added in Entity Framework 2.1. So you have to upgrade your application to ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Then install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` nuget package and configure it as follows in the `ConfigureServices()` method of the `Startup` class.

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(YourConnectionString));
```

Here is the more details about Lazy Loading in Entity Framework Core 2.1:

1. [What's new in Entity Framework 2.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1/)
2. [Lazy Loading Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178824/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-pooria-sadeghy).

Comment: thanx my friend, very very much for your great help